# Bidirectional mapping not working since it's not saving correctly

Tags: spring, hibernate, bidirectional

I am new to Spring and I am testing the API on postman and the instructor_id is not saving.
This is how I am testing it on postman and don't know if it is right or not.

```
{ 
    "coursename":"tesasdasdast",
    "description":"tesdasdsadasting",
    "userEntity":{ 
        "instructor_id":1
    }
}
```

Steps:

I have two entities:
UserEntity
CourseEntity

I have a controller where I'm saving the information called:
CourseController

I have a repository called CourseRepo and I am extending JpaRepository

In CourseEntity:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
private UserEntity userEntity;
```

In UserEntity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userEntity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CourseEntity> courseEntity;
```

In my CourseController:

```java
@PostMapping("/courses")
void addCourse(@RequestBody CourseEntity course) {
    courseRepository.save(course);
}
```

I have added in my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is the error message that I'm getting in postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-10T16:51:47.780+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.finaly.projectback.entity.CourseEntity.userEntity -> com.finaly.projectback.entity.UserEntity; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.finaly.projectback.entity.CourseEntity.userEntity -> com.finaly.projectback.entity.UserEntity",
    "path": "/project/courses"
}
```

And these two are the tables in the database:

```
create table web_user(
    id INT primary key auto_increment,
    firstname VARCHAR(50),
    lastname VARCHAR(50),
    username VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    pwd VARCHAR(50),
    user_role_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_role_id) REFERENCES web_user_role(id)
);

CREATE TABLE web_course (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    coursename VARCHAR(50),
    instructor_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (instructor_id) REFERENCES web_user(id)
);
```

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Your repository/DAO class would be helpful to know how you try to save the object. It looks like you're trying to save a relationship which is not synchronised properly. Have a look [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) to read more about synchronisation of bidirectional relationships/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are correctly setting entities in associations.
userEntity.setCourseEntity and courseEntity.setUserEntity

Do you have this code in place and then check your hibernate queries that are fired on save method call.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. Instead of creating the foreign key as user_entity_user_id, i was creating it as user_id.

It seems like a stupid mistake but I'm still new to Spring and for now, many things look like magic.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.